# Sequlize Postgres id auto increment not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am using Node, sequlize, Postgres to develop a application. 
I have a model called `User`

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
})
module.exports = User;
```

Migration ok with out any error.

But when I am going to insert data without id its saving id as null ?

```
return modelName.create(body).then((payload) => {
    payload.success = true
    return payload
}).catch(err => {
    err.success = false
    return err
})
```

its saving all data without id.

```
sequlize version
"sequelize": "^5.21.3"
```

Comment: Hi, I work with many tables that they have auto increment id and this code works fine for me. 
Are you sure that you have create in your SQL Db the primary key to be also auto increment ?

Comment: Also Sequelize adjust with your DB so if you can avoid to add a primary key because sequelize will do it for you

Comment: I have created migration to create the table automatically and postgres don,t have any autoincrement option.

Comment: Can you try to run a statement. 
https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-define-an-auto-increment-primary-key-in-postgresql/

Comment: ok I will let you know after try ..